# moving web development environment (xampp) from old computer (xp) to new computer (windows 7)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'd like to setup xampp on different computer. The problem is that i've changed php.ini, added databases, etc. I could redo the changes. but i feel like that's not the principled thing to do.

Is is simple as installing xampp on my new machine and then copying all my files from the old installation? thank you in advance

Comment: ib10 was being used by a different program. what's ib10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always install a new environment on different system rather then copy it from somewhere else, because I never remember (and don't want to remember) which settings are platform specific and which aren't. Also it's usually easier.

However, you can try to just copy the `php.ini` (and maybe other configuration files, like the ones for apache and mysql) to the new system. Remember to backup the old files first.

For the database you should have a schema file (as SQL-file) to create the database structure anyway. For the db-content (and maybe -- if missing -- the schema) you can create a SQL-dump file from the old database.

Comment: what are these other configuration files?

Comment: "like the ones for apache and mysql", namely `httpd.conf`, `my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

For the PHP stuff it's enough to copy the PHP files and configuration. Same with the HTTPd stuff. For the database, you'll want to use `mysqladmin`/`mysqldump`/`mysql` to dump the database on the old system and load it on the new.

Comment: is the dumping the database a simple copy and paste deal?

Comment: No. The copy-and-paste comes *after* you've dumped.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all your source files into the new server and that should be enough. You will have to redo your settings and databases or if you are comfortable, you may copy your settings file. Regarding creation of databases, I always have a sql file which contains all database creation statements checked into source control. Whenever I need a fresh database, I just run the script.

As an aside, I'm assuming you're comfortable with the various components and since you're starting from a fresh instance, you might want to consider installing all the components separately instead.